# Can a .Net Core / Angular2 be hosted on any .Net service provider?

Tags: angular, .net-core, hosting

I am creating my first .Net Core / Angular2 app.   I have gone through a few tutorials on both and can create them indpendently but the Angular app runs on node.   I have created a Core/Angular app locally.  When I use a .net project the tutorial says it's spinning up a node service locally.   I can find resources on hosting on Azure but i don't want to host there.  Does anyone konw if Core/Angular2 apps can be hosted on any .Net hosting provider?   If so is there a resource on the server requirements, components, setup, etc?

Answer (score 2):

An angular app once it's built (using the `ng build` command) is simply a static site-- it doesn't need node to run. In that sense, you can host it anywhere you would typically host static web content

If you want see this in action, build the project, and open the `index.html` file in your browser.

Comment: Also, .Net Core compiled app runs anywhere (if you're not using WPF etc. of .Net Core 3.0)